# Need Airbus A380 model in .xml format

Tags: airbus, airbus-a380, software

i am looking for Airbus A380 aircraft model in xml language/ format. Can anyone provide? Or share the xml code?

Comment: 'xml' is not a format for describing 3D models. Even if this were possible, you would need much more information about how the data is stored than just saying "it's XML'.

Comment: Do you mean [VRML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML)?

Answer (score 1):

There are community sites that create and share 3D software models of just about anything, including planes. Here is one for [the A380](https://grabcad.com/library/airbus-a380-4), found by Googling. I can't vouch for its accuracy or correctness.

If this link breaks then you can search the same site for other postings, or for other similar sites.

Comment: Please don’t post link only answers, without the link this answer isn’t much use.

Comment: @Notts90 Exactly what are you expecting in answer to this, other than a link to the thing the questioner asked for? The actual file is far too big to be uploaded to the answer.

Comment: I don’t expect this question to be answered (it’s now closed). Even if it wasn’t closed as unclear it would be off topic as it can only really be answered with a link, which isn’t a good fit for this site as links rot.

Comment: Here’s the meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/335608

Comment: And here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/335608

Comment: Rules are good, but they have exceptions. If the question is "where do I find this on the web" then the answer is going to fundamentally be a link. What the meta says is "Linking is not a bad thing as long as you actually provide some context to your answer.  At the very least you could explain where the link goes and what it is going to show the user." Check and check.